# How important is the usage of open_basedir on a server with multiple different PHP websites?

Tags: php, http, webserver, apache, server

On an apache webserver with multiple VirtualHosts running different PHP websites on different domains, how important is it to set open_basedir for each VirtualHost?

Will it actually help to isolate the different VHosts from each other or is it possible to circumvent the restriction?

How big of a security flaw is it to not set open_basedir under the described circumstances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It adds additional protection in case of a directory traversal vulnerability. For example, consider a PHP file that looks like this:

```
readfile($_GET['thumbnail_path']);
```

Without `open_basedir`, this page could be used to read any file on the filesystem. Setting `open_basedir` prevents this, so that only files in some specific directory can be read.

However, `open_basedir` does not protect against someone that can run (PHP) code on the server. For example, simply running `system('cat /etc/passwd')` will bypass the basedir setting. Also, [not all functions that handle files check the path against the open_basedir setting](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2017/04/26/php-open-basedir/).

Answer (score 0):

open_basedir basically limits operations to a userspace, a directory in the filesystem namely their home directory. You can set it to multiple directories if needed.

setting open_basedir prevents accessing/modifying a location outside of the specified space be it intentional or accidental.

If there is a vulnerability in a PHP script or malicious php scripts in the userspace, it limits the malicious script access to the directory/directories. Making it difficult for them to pull files like passwd, shadow files or any other sensitive areas.